# Where am I messing up my links that are looped in my ajax call using the Google Books API?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, api

I have a webpage that loads google books from the Google Books API based upon a user entered search. The page displays the title as a link and the small thumbnail. I cannot get my links to work properly they keep redirecting me to Google's 404 not found page. I feel like I am missing something very simple but need some extra eyes to find it. I have tried too many different things...
Also, I tried to console.log() the id attribute to even see if it was being received and stored but it won't show anything for that either

I have tried to use this.id, data.items[i].id and even tried to get the ISBN and get to the Google page via the ISBN link that is shown on the Google Books API examples on their website

```
function bookSearch(){
  var search = document.getElementById('search').value
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = ""
  console.log(search)


  $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search,
  dataType: "json",

  success: function(data) {
      for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i ++){
          var bookid = data.items[i].id;
          console.log(bookid);
          results.innerHTML += "<a 
href='https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/" + bookid+ "'><br/> 
   <br/><br/>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "</a>"
          results.innerHTML += '<br><img src="' + 
    data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail + '">'
      }
  },
  type:'GET'
});
}

window.onload=function(){
.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', bookSearch, false)
}
```

//Thats my js file that links to my html. Making bookid a var was the last thing I have tried

//This is my html code where you enter your search query and it prints out data from the API

```
<h1>Book Search</h1>

<input id="search" placeholder="Search">

<button id="button" type="button">Go</button>
```

It should redirect the user to the corresponding books individual page but it gives me a 404 instead.

Comment: Sorry to point out the obvious, but it's the wrong URL.  Make sure you're constructing the correct URL.  Can't really help without knowing what URL you're making and what URL you want to make.

Comment: the URL is correct, but it is missing a parameter

Answer (score -1):

add some semicolons `;` to the end of your lines of code, the whole booksearch function will run together and not work, more than likely this is what is stopping your code.

you are missing some syntax. the second to last line should read document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', bookSearch, false); and you dont need a `;` on the end, but its a good habit to get into.

you need to pass the API a variable in the query string. try something like this to get results `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=javascript`